# Loading fonts into Sass with Webpack 5

Tags: sass, fonts, webpack-5

Strange one with my custom Webpack config.

I'm trying to import some fonts into a scss file as below, which sits at `styles/abstracts/_fonts.scss`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "montserratblack";
  src: url("../../assets/fonts/montserrat-black.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../../assets/fonts/montserrat-black.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

The `assets` directory is at the same level as `styles`

From this file, it will not compile ('Can't resolve' error) - but if I move the imports up a level into the styles directory `styles.scss` and adjust the url path accordingly, everything works fine.

What gives?

Comment: Haven't directly solved the issue but got around it by using my '@src' alias from my Webpack config. Would still like to know the underlying problem, though!